# javascript declare function with timeout

Tags: javascript

I have javascript like and i want to set time delay to this function parameters.here is my simple function

```
function mopen(id)
    {   

        mcancelclosetime();

        if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
        ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

    }
```

and here i want to set a timeout delay with id.I mean

the id should open with a time delay like this

```
function settimeout(mopen(id),1000)
{
}
```

But My this try is not working please help me how can i do this

**Update**

here is my loop function

```
 function hideshow(span) {
        hideDiv();
        var div = document.getElementById("DIV_" + span.id);
        if (div.style.display == "none")
        setTimeout(div.style.display = "block",2000);
        else
            div.style.display = "none"; 
    }
```

can u please now tell me how to settimeout for the div to become a block.I have set it but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was already given (not in the way you expected, I suppose). Rewrite your function as

```
 function hideshow(span) {
    hideDiv();
    var div = document.getElementById("DIV_" + span.id);
    if (div.style.display == "none")
        setTimeout(function() { div.style.display = "block" }, 2000);
    else
        div.style.display = "none"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `mopen()` in an anonymous function passed to `setTimeout()`.

```
var t = setTimeout(function() {
  mopen(id)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sir Actualy i have to call this function on minimum a 500 hyperlink and i want to set a generic timeout for all links .If this is not possible then i have to find all link and write the new code for calling the function.There fore i want to set timeout in declaring function not on calling.

Comment: @user1220667 So your intent is to bind this timeout to `<a>` tags, onclick, for example?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, you can simply do this. In your case your defining a function called setTimeout, which is not necessary, this method is already available in the browser's Javascript standard library.

```
 setTimeout( function(){mopen(id)}, 1000);
```

Generally you can just do

```
 setTimeout( yourFunction, 1000);
```

which works perfectly, but when you have to pass parameters to a function in setTimeout, you can use first version, as in call it inside an anonymous "function () {}" call.

Comment: Sir I already tried this Method but My Work Will be too long to apply on all links .I want there should be possibility of time out in declaring function so that my all link will be updated automatilcally